# Django - two approaches to extending user model wont work together?

Tags: django, django-users

I am trying to make my django app require a unique email address when creating the account. When I added (the commented line in the models) the unique email constraint in the model I used to add fields before it just adds another email field instead of altering the original one.

So after having found another solution with extending the AbstractUser class unfortunately Im getting 'the model User is not registered' error when im trying to make migrations.

Please advice me on what would be a way to go to have both extra fields as well as unique email constraint.

Heres how i have extra fields added to the user model:

models

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #### email = models.EmailField(("email address"), blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True,
                                              choices =[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from account.models import Account
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class AccountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Account
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'
    
class CustomizedUserAdmin (UserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccountInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomizedUserAdmin)
```

It worked **until** ive added:

models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the user models not both whether to use "User" or "CustomUser".

So, in your models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your admin do the same.

Comment: This code snippet makes no sense. What is the point of creating new model that only contains relation to different model?

Answer (score 0):

From the moment you declare `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'`
you have to use it as the only one valid user model. So the error totally makes sense as you are using Django user model in admin. Adjust admin to use **CustomUser** model and you are probably good to go.